# Passing function on self without parameters to the function (like map/filter etc.) doesn't call the function but wraps as a block without args

Tags: swift, types, higher-order-functions

Given:

```
class Elem {
    func f() -> AnotherElem {
        return AnotherElem(elem: self)
    } 
}
```

I want to call the map function on array of `Elem`s passing the function f:

Sample code:

```
collection.map { $0.f() }
```

However, I don't like this `{}` notation so I was thinking whether or not I can pass a function as an argument (which in my eyes increases readability), and indeed I can
What I want is to do the following:

```
collection.map(Elem.f)
```

The last is valid syntax however the type of the array is the following: `[() -> AnotherElem]` instead of expected `[AnotherElem]` type.

Is a bug or a feature?

Obviously, this could be solved by calling `map` again and calling the array of blocks, but this is not the problem I'm having.

I'm struggling to understand why it is the way it is

Comment: Make `f` as `static func`: `static func f(_ elem: Elem) -> AnotherElem { return AnotherElem(elem: elem) }` then `collection.map(Elem.f)` will work as you want.

Comment: well, this is a workaround and not a good OOP design I would say. Don't think my colleagues will be happy about it

Comment: Then learn to love `collection.map { $0.f() }`, because there's absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It kinda looks ugly. imo. Unnecessary dollars or variable names when I just want to invoke a function ;(

Comment: It seems to me that the function to create `AnotherElem` from an `Elem` could be defined as an initializer on `AnotherElem`: `init(_ elem: Elem) {
        // so something with elem
    }` then you'd call it with `collection.map(AnotherElem.init)`.

Comment: @vacawama valid point, but not applicable for every case. Imagine I want a list of number of rows in a section. Having a new Init on integer that takes an array of rows seems ridiculous

Comment: @denis631 I totally agree. It's just more aesthetically pleasing without the `{` and `$` symbols. Another thing I would like to mention is properties. If `Elem` has a property `p` of type `T`, I wish `Elem.p` can be converted to `(Elem) -> T`, but nope. I have to use closure syntax :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, i.e. not a bug.

If you try to use an instance method `someMethod` of the form`(T) -> U` directly like this:

```
SomeType.someMethod
```

The type of that expression is `(SomeType) -> (T) -> U`. In your case, The type of `Elem.f` is `(Elem) -> () -> AnotherElem`.

Why is it designed like this? It is so that you can pass an instance to `SomeType.someMethod`, and then get the original instance method:

```
let f = SomeType.someMethod(instanceOfSomeType)
```

I guess this could be somewhat called "currying".

Anyway, you would need another function to transform `Elem.f`:

```
func uncurry<T, U>(_ f: @escaping (T) -> () -> U) -> (T) -> U {
    return { f($0)() }
}
```

Now passing `uncurry(Elem.f)` will work.

Comment: so there is no way to pass function name to the map function in order for it to be invoked. I would either need the block syntax or syntactic sugar like the function you have written (foo), right?

Comment: @denis631 I wish Swift had something like this, but no. :(

Comment: @denis631 Just recalled that `foo` is _uncurrying_ the function. It should be called `uncurry`.

Comment: I think `invoke` would be a better name, but it doesn't matter

Comment: I've heard about currying, but not about uncurrying. Learning something new everyday. Thanks :)